# LinearLayout's child view change line according to device's width issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

Hi friends I am using `LinearLayout` with **orientation** `horizontal` to fill `TextView's` inside it programmatically.

**Code:**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hello " + i);
    linearLayout.addView(textView, i);
}
```

now, i am getting very weird look on the screen:

[image]

and I want this type of view:

[image]

views inside the `LinearLayout` should **change** their **line** according to device width. Anyone has any idea to achieve this, please help.

Comment: According to me you have to use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.

Comment: @ChintanBawa can you share any link or any example ?

Comment: http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/ .

Comment: Did u achieved you requirement?

Answer (score 0):

add text views to grid layout with setNumColumns().

Comment: this should be as a comemnt or give proper explanation and code if needed.